# this.debug is not a function Angular Universal

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular10

I'm applying SSR in my project by using Angular 10.

I've found that lot of people recommend using `domino`.

Below is my `server.ts` file

```
...

import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { createWindow } from 'domino';

const scripts = readFileSync('dist/video-website-angular/browser/index.html').toString();

const window = createWindow(scripts);
global['window'] = window;

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

...
```

When I run `npm run dev:ssr`, I get the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vMxM.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `this.debug is not a function` error is just a side effect. The actual error is the first one:

[image]

In order to fix it, you need to declare window as any, like this:

```js
const window: any = createWindow(scripts);

// or via a cast

const window = createWindow(scripts) as any;
```

There is also another approach, that I like least since it practically make the TS code behave like JS, and cut all the typing and code hints support, but here it goes:

```js
(global as any).window = window;
(global as any).document = window.document;
(global as any).Event = window.Event;
(global as any).KeyboardEvent = window.KeyboardEvent;
```

Either of these should fix your issue.

Comment: My `global['window']` was already assigned and only now suddenly started getting this error. I'm assuming the 3rd-party libs are conditionally dependant on `this.debug`, but not sure why now. All I did was switch branches and did a `npm i`. Switching back and running `npm i` did not help even after removing `node_modules`. I'm screwed.

Comment: Sometimes switching branches might mess up the node_modules. What you can try is to run a `rm -frd node_modules` and then `npm i` again. Hopefully it would solve it for you.

Comment: @mikeandtherest, do you know how to prevent the compiler from exiting on such error?

Comment: I added the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151309/how-can-we-prevent-this-debug-is-not-a-function-from-causing-the-compiler-to-exi

Answer (score 0):

Try 'npm install' - then run it again after the packages are added