# How can we prevent this.debug is not a function from causing the compiler to exit

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

In reference to the question asked here [this.debug is not a function Angular Universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966642/this-debug-is-not-a-function-angular-universal) . it is correct that `this.debug is not a function` is just a side effect, however such error leads the compiler to stop (when watching) during the development.

How can I prevent such behavior on such errors?

Also, it sometimes just randomly simply stops, see screenshot below, it shows compilation complete then angular is listening then after I refreshed the UI, it just simply stopped no errors nothing.

[image]

I think it might be related to `nguniversal`, I created https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2200 issue. I really hope anyone can really help.

When I run `ng run serve-ssr`, I expect the angular server will run and watch for changes, and per my changes, it would rebuild (which it does pretty great) but all that continues just till an error happens or a mistake in the code. In that sense, it would stop and exit.

I don't know if this is a bug or not, I just upgraded my angular to 12 and nguniversal to v12 hoping that this issue would go away but it didn't and I don't know where to go.

I am working on a complicated project that takes some good time to compile from scratch. When running in dev environment and I make a accident and write something wrong, I'd get the error of that wrong and then the `this.debug is not a function` message will come up then the watch/compiler will stop.

`angular.json`:

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
"build-for-ssr": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.template.html",
            "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/intro.js",
                "output": "./assets/intro.js/"
              },
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/monaco-editor", "output": "assets/monaco-editor" }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/intro.js/introjs.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/intro.js/intro.js"],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
"serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "build-for-ssr",
            "serverTarget": "server"
          },
        },
```

Comment: This is tricky, because even if we find a workaround to make the `this.debug is not a function` to not break the build, the actual error that caused the side effect will still be there. So exactly as for the other question, we need to fix the root cause.

Comment: If you can, please share the build logs including the errors you get.

Comment: @mikeandtherest, I totally agree, it would make sense if the watch could just pause on the error, but not necessarily exit completely. I have did my best to find logs or even the root cause beside the originated error from my code, but I couldn't get one that would explain why `this.debug is not a function` or why would this command lead to an actual exit. Is it not common to happen with you?

Comment: Can you please help me understand where I can get such logs that might help?

Comment: You mean you don't get any relevant error during `ng start` or `ng build`? Basically the other question where I was able to help, had a link with a screenshot of ng start where I could see that the issue was coming from `global.window` not being recognized.  I expect that you also have something helpful in the ng start or build logs?

Comment: @mikeandtherest, please see the screenshot, I'll try to see if I can get a snapshot of the `global.window`, its kind of difficult for me to do, as it really happens randomly. What I want to avoid is the "stop" that it does. I want to the `watch` to keep `watching` for file change then retries.

Comment: @mikeandtherest I really don't think it's `global.window`, I added more info, please see my question. I also created https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2200 , I don't believe that the behavior at any case should make the `watch` or the command to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue, as per [this comment](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1848#issuecomment-877819300), I updated `return attempts > 10 || !allowedErrorCodes.includes(error.code)` to `return attempts > 10000 || !allowedErrorCodes.includes(error.code)` in this file `node_modules/@nguniversal/builders/src/ssr-dev-server/utils.js`, and ever since, I didn't experience the compiler exiting or gets interrupted during development when a mistake in the code is done.

The only trick, this won't impact if you run `ng run serve-ssr` with something wrong in the code. You'd still get `this.debug is not a function` still. But once it's fixed and you run it. it won't get interrupted regardless the mistake you do in the code.

**Edit** Updated the directory location to the full path.

Comment: I couldn't find the directory, could you please tell me if it is in the node modules or not? I have seen in the node modules but it isn't there in my project.

Comment: Yes, it's in the node_modules dir, in `node_modules/@nguniversal/builders/src/ssr-dev-server/utils.js`. I think that this is fixed in the latest version of Angular if the change is no longer needed there.